# how do i create a new link in node.tpl.php by preprocess function in drupal?

Tags: nodes, theming

I have content type in which I have two or three links .In node.tpl.php, all links are displaying from a single variable "$links" in node.tpl.php. i want to remove one particular link from the "$links" variable by preprocess function and assign that link to a new variables , so i can display it where ever I want.

I created a preprocess function  to implement it

```
function sample_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  if($variables['type']="product"){
    $node=$variables['node'];
    $create_review=array();
    $create_review=$node->links['review_field_product_review'];
    $variables['create_review']=$create_review;
    unset($node->links['shopping_review_field_shopping_product_review']);
  }
}
```

and I pasted the following code in node.tpl.php

```
print $create_review;
```

It displays "array" in product page and that particular link is not removed from the variable ($links) in node.tpl.php

Can you tell me how to remove the particular link from the "$link " variable in node.tpl.php and display it by another variable in node.tpl.php?

Comment: ignore this comment

Answer (score 2):

This line will always return true, since you are assigning a value with the '=' operator:

```
if($variables['type']="product"){
```

This should be a comparison, so use '==':

```
if($variables['type']=="product"){
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $variables['create_review']=$create_review;
```

Should be

```
  $variables['create_review'] = theme('links', $create_review);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but product page was not loaded when i replaced the code as per your instruction.Can you tell me what may be the problem?

Comment: Reload the page, then check your php error log. What's the last entry?